# How to adjust a variable based on the id of the object that is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a shop system for my HTML game, and I want to make it so that when you click on an item, it gets the id, and lowers the variable for that item by 1.

```javascript
if(e.shiftKey && inShop[this.id] === 0) {
    coins = coins+price[this.id]
    coinUpdate();
    [this.id]--;    
}

var fish1 = 1
```

```html
<html>
    <img class="item cookable" id="fish1" src="source">
</html>
```

For example, when I click on a fish, I want it to lower the variable for how many fishes you have in your inventory. So I need to change the `[this.id]` in a variable with the same name.

Comment: could you perhaps provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `window` method. It only works with `global` variables.

Global variables are defined as `some_var = 10;` as opposed to `var some_var = 10;` If you're from a desktop programming background, you'll find globals in JS hella awkward.

Instead, use namespaces or an object (this method).

Define your inventory like this:

```
var inventory = {
    goldfish: 10,
    seahorse: 10,
    jellyfish: 10
}
```

As for the HTML, the ID method is OK, but why not use the `data` attribute? It's made to hold metadata so perfect for this scenario.

```
<img src="//placehold.it/32x32" class="item cookable" data-type="fish">
```

Access for this is built into jQuery via the .data method so when you need to decrement or increment the quantity based on what is clicked, simply use the following where necessary:

```
// Fetch the "type" of fish from the data attribute
var type = $(this).data("type");

// And update the inventory
inventory[type]--;
```

Use the `data` attribute for other metadata so `data-foo="hello" data-bar="world"`

And these can be fetched as an object using jQuery `.data()` and it will return `{foo: "hello", bar: "world"} or fetch them individually by passing the data name`.data("foo")`

Personally, I'd use this as opposed to ID.

Comment: But what is the difference between data-type and id?

Comment: You can use ID if you want, there difference between the two being that the `data-` attribute is made specifically to store metadata about something. Read this page for a better description: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

All *global* variables in JS are created on the window object. If you have a variable per id, then you just need to do `window[this.id]--` or `window[this.id]++`. Anyway, in JavaScript the Window object acts as the global namespace and in general it is bad practice to clutter the global namespace with variables. You should create a new object (for example `items`) containing all the item counters and for each item that is added you can do `items[this.id]++` or `items[this.id]--` when they are removed

Comment: _All variables in JS are created on the window object._ This is **not** true.  Only variables declared outside any functions are add to the global object as properties.

Answer (score 1):

`[this.id]--` is not going to work.  This makes an array with a single element (the string that is referenced by `this.id`), and tries to decrement that array.  And decrementing an array doesn't make much sense.

You can't access local variable dynamically like this (well you can in some cases, but really you shouldn't). However, you *can* do it with properties, so you have to rejigger things a bit.

How about storing all the counts of things you have in an object, maybe call it `inventory`.

```
var inventory = {
    fish1: 10,
    fish2: 5,
    worms: 3
};
```

Now you use you decrement method with only a slight tweak:

```
if(e.shiftKey && inShop[this.id] === 0) {
    coins = coins+price[this.id]
    coinUpdate();
    inventory[this.id]--; // decrement an item count in your inventory
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm changing it to this now, I'll let you know if it worked